# "If" Function returns true with formula in cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two columns: The reference column with a "vlookup" formula to return a test score from another sheet. The other with an "if" formula to show "1" if that reference column is greater than or equal to 70%. However, the "if" formula is also returning "1" if the vlookup column shows a blank cell. How do I get it to return nothing if there is nothing in the reference column? I have tried the following two formulas:

=IF(L4>=.7,"1","0")
=IFERROR(IF(L4>=0.7,"1","0"),"")

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTNQH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change the formula to:

```
=IF(AND(L4>=0.7,L4<>""),"1","0")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two tests here:

1. Is the cell greater than or equal to 0.7
2. Is the cell empty

You can use IFS for this:

[image]

```
=IFS($A$1:$A$5>=0.7,1,$A$1:$A$5<>"",0,TRUE,"")
```

Note that I have selected the entire array in both logical conditions. This means you only need put the formula in the top cell. The fifth row correctly returns an empty cell because column A is empty.